# Resize drawn rectangle to fit original image

Tags: c#, wpf, crop, rectangles, imaging

I'm developing an application to manipulate images scanned on a wide-image scanner. These images are shown as a `ImageBrush` on a `Canvas`.
On this `Canvas` they can a make `Rectangle` with the mouse, to define an area to be cropped.

My problem here is to resize the `Rectangle` according to the original image size, so that it crops the exact area on the original image.

I've tried many things so far and it's just sqeezing my brain, to figure out the right solution.
I know that I need to get the percent that the original image is bigger than the image shown on the canvas.

The dimentions of the original image are:

> h: 5606
>   w: 7677

And when I show the image, they are:

> h: 1058,04
>   w: 1910

Which gives these numbers:

```
float percentWidth = ((originalWidth - resizedWidth) / originalWidth) * 100;
float percentHeight = ((originalHeight - resizedHeight) / originalHeight) * 100;

percentWidth = 75,12049
percentHeight = 81,12665
```

From here I can't figure how to resize the `Rectangle` correctly, to fit the original image.

My last approach was this:

```
int newRectWidth = (int)((originalWidth * percentWidth) / 100);
int newRectHeight = (int)((originalHeight * percentHeight) / 100);
int newRectX = (int)(rectX + ((rectX * percentWidth) / 100));
int newRectY = (int)(rectY + ((rectY * percentHeight) / 100));
```

Hopefully someone can lead me in the right direction, because i'm off track here and I can't see what i'm missing.

**Solution**

```
    private System.Drawing.Rectangle FitRectangleToOriginal(
        float resizedWidth,
        float resizedHeight,
        float originalWidth,
        float originalHeight,
        float rectWidth,
        float rectHeight,
        double rectX,
        double rectY)
    {
        // Calculate the ratio between original and resized image
        float ratioWidth = originalWidth / resizedWidth;
        float ratioHeight = originalHeight / resizedHeight;

        // create a new rectagle, by resizing the old values
        // by the ratio calculated above
        int newRectWidth = (int)(rectWidth * ratioWidth);
        int newRectHeight = (int)(rectHeight * ratioHeight);
        int newRectX = (int)(rectX * ratioWidth);
        int newRectY = (int)(rectY * ratioHeight);

        return new System.Drawing.Rectangle(newRectX, newRectY, newRectWidth, newRectHeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually doing a form of projection. Don't use percentages, just use the ratio between  5606 and 1058,4 = ~5.30. When the user drags the rectangle, reproject it which is `selectedWidth * 5606/1058.4`.

Comment: Oh damn you!!! Actually this was the first approach i tried, but I must have done something wrong, because now it works! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only reliable option is to let your users zoom in to the image (100% or higher zoom level) and make a selection on part of the image. This way they can make an exact pixel-based selection. (Assuming that the purpose of your selection rectangle is to select part of an image.)

Your problem now is that you're using floating-point calculations because of the 75% zoom level and rounding errors will make your selection rectangles inaccurate. No matter what you do, when you try to make a selection on a shrinked image, you're not selecting exact pixels - you're selecting parts of pixels as you resize your rectangle. Since a partial pixel cannot be selected, the selection edges will be rounded up or down so you either select one pixel too many or one pixel too few in a given direction.

Another issue that I just noticed is that you distort your image - horizontally it's 75% zoom, vertically it's 81%. This makes it even harder for users because the image will be smoothed differently in the two directions. Horizontally 4 original pixels will be interpolated on 3 output pixels; vertically 5 original pixels will be interpolated on 4 output pixels.

Comment: Good read actually, even tho it doesn't solve my problem. But this just leads to the point/answer given by ranieuwe...don't use procent when calculating image width/height +1 from here :)